# SSRS bar chart date formatting

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I am looking to get weekdays in order, can anyone please help?

At the minute the order is Mon, Weds, Thur, Tue, Fri.

I have removed the `A-Z` from the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a field in your dataset that contains the weekdays you can create a calculated field for your dataset and set this expression:

```
=Switch(
Fields!weekday.Value = "Mon", 1,
Fields!weekday.Value = "Tue", 2,
Fields!weekday.Value = "Wed", 3,
Fields!weekday.Value = "Thu", 4,
Fields!weekday.Value = "Fri", 5,
Fields!weekday.Value = "Sat", 6,
Fields!weekday.Value = "Sun", 7
)
```

Then you can use the calculated field to sort ascending `A-Z` or descending `Z-A`.

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Worked , had to add comma after 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 .